# What does the gradient of the gradient ($\nabla\nabla u$) mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, vector-analysis

For a scalar function $u$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have this equality:
$$\nabla(|\nabla u|^{p-2})=(p-2)|\nabla u|^{p-4}\nabla u\nabla\nabla u$$

My question is : what does $\nabla\nabla u$ mean? I only know the signification of the gradient of a function, but here will it be the gradient of a vector field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat awkward notation for the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), an $n\times n$ matrix of second derivatives. The gradient $\nabla u$ is a row vector, so $\nabla u \nabla\nabla u$ is the result of vector-matrix multiplication, also a row vector.

(One usually does not use $\nabla^2 u$ for Hessian because it'd be confused with the Laplacian. Some authors write $D^2u$ for the Hessian, and even switch from $\nabla u$ to $Du$ for consistency with that.)

More generally, if 
$$f=\begin{pmatrix}f_1\\f_2\\f_3\end{pmatrix}$$ is a vector field, then 
$$\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}\nabla f_1\\\nabla f_2\\\nabla f_3\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: thank you for unswering i think that know i have an idea about it so what will be the $\nabla f$ if $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3) $ (vector field)

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: well done and good job thank you very much

Comment: Of course, the notation for the Laplacian is wrong; it should be $\lVert{\nabla}\rVert^2$.

Comment: Ryan, this is such a great point!